# to_dataframe() bug when query returns no results

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

If a valid BigQuery query returns 0 rows, to_dataframe() crashes.  (btw, I am running this on Google Cloud Datalab)

for example:

```
q = bq.Query('SELECT * FROM [isb-cgc:tcga_201510_alpha.Somatic_Mutation_calls] WHERE ( Protein_Change="V600E" ) LIMIT 10')
r = q.results()
r.to_dataframe()
```

produces:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-de55245104c0> in <module>()
----> 1 r.to_dataframe()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gcp/bigquery/_table.pyc in to_dataframe(self, start_row, max_rows)
    628     # Need to reorder the dataframe to preserve column ordering
    629     ordered_fields = [field.name for field in self.schema]
--> 630     return df[ordered_fields]
    631 
    632   def to_file(self, destination, format='csv', csv_delimiter=',', csv_header=True):

TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

is this a known bug?

Comment: Please look for and report bugs on the issue tracker https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datalab/issues

Comment: done: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datalab/issues/678

Comment: Fixed in 4d92929 (by GrahamW)  --  thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly not a known bug. Please do log a bug as mentioned by Felipe.

Contributions, both bug reports, and of course fixes, are welcome! :)